# Prevent instantiation of an object outside its factory method

Tags: c++, oop, factory-pattern

Suppose I have a class with a factory method

```
class A {
public:
  static A* newA()
  {
    // Some code, logging, ...
    return new A();
  }
}
```

Is it possible to prevent the instantiation of an object of this class with a `new`, so that factory method is the only method to create an instance of the object?

Comment: Singletons are evil. See here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what

Comment: @Truth: This doesn't look like a singleton.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: A factory which returns an instance of itself and prevents anyone else from instantiating it? Looks dangerously close.

Comment: This is not actually a singleton (there will be multiple instances), but I get the point. I try to avoid them.

Comment: This pattern is perfectly fine, and used for various reasons (and has nothing to do with a singleton, which is evil). Better yet is to return a smart pointer of some kind (especially sweet when you need `std::enable_shared_from_this`, or when you manipulate garbage collected handles).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure; just make the constructor private (protected if this is a base class):

```
class A {
public:
  static A* newA()
  {
    // Some code, logging, ...
    return new A();
  }

private:
  A() {}  // Default constructor
};
```

You should make the copy constructor private/protected as well, if required.

And as always, you should strongly consider returning a smart pointer rather than a raw pointer, in order to simplify memory management issues.

Comment: This answer just screams of `std::unique_ptr`...Edit: Meh, don't go ghost-editing your answer. :P

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As for the smart pointers - I know. I would normally use them. But memory management for this particular object is a bit complicated and cannot use `shared_ptr`everywhere for performance reasons.

Comment: I always wondered, suppose your factory returns a unique_ptr<A> but one actually wants a shared_ptr (or vice-versa), how would one do that?

Comment: @stijn: there is a conversion from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr`. Return the former if you can, the latter if you must.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to make the copy constructor private as well or with new C++11 syntax you can explicitly tell the compiler to not copy it and make the default constructor private with something like this:

```
struct NonCopyable {
    NonCopyable & operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable() = default;
};

class A : NonCopyable {
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<A> newA()
  {
    // Some code, logging, ...
    return std::make_shared<A>();
  }

private:
  A() {}  // Default constructor
};
```

The C++03 way was usually something like this:

```
class A {
public:
  static A* newA()
  {
    // Some code, logging, ...
    return new A();
  }

private:
  A() {}                        // no outsider default constructor
  A(const A& rhs);              // no copy
  A& operator=(const A& rhs);   // no assignment
};

int main()
{
    A x;        // C2248
    A y(x);     // C2248
    x = y;      // C2248
    A* p = A::newA(); // OK
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point, actually I would avoid most of this and just use `std::unique_ptr` in most cases probably.

Comment: C++11's way [doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/aosfoE) as-is. require some tweak [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n7W4Me)