# C++ - How to reserve some class objects to only be instantiated by a certain class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I'm defining a unique_id_generator class, which is kind of, sort of a singleton i.e there is just one instance for a given type_id. There can be many different type_ids, but for a specific type_id, there is just one instance.
Now I want to make sure that type_id = 0 goes to a very specific class. Basically just that specific class can use type_id = 0 and then the rest can be used freely.
I'm wondering through which design pattern can I ensure that happens?
I don't want to control or govern type_ids given in general.
FYI, I'm already using a private constructor to block un-guarded instantiation of the class.

I can't control who instantiates a unique_id_generator first. Also based on design, I don't want to route requests for unique ids through the specific class which gets type_id = 0.

Any thoughts/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent instantiation of an object outside its factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558393/prevent-instantiation-of-an-object-outside-its-factory-method)

Comment: Not really. I already made the constructor private for singleton. I want a specific class to get type_id = 0. No one else to be able to get an instance for type_id = 0. I don't like the friend class notion in C++ but I might have to go that route.

Comment: Then if make factory method to be private, and make that specific class to be a friend class. Would that work?

Comment: Yeah, my mind is somewhere around that idea. Can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could think of is to define 2 instantiation methods. One public and one private as follows:

```
#define EXCLUSIVE_CNT 1

class UniqueID
{
public:
    friend class MySpecialClass;

    static UniqueID * GetInstance(int type_id)
    {
        assert(type_id >= EXCLUSIVE_CNT);

        return Instantiate(type_id);
    }

private:
    int type_id_;
    int seq_id_;
    std::map<type_id, UniqueID*> type_to_obj_map_;

    UniqueID(int type_id)
    {
        type_id_ = type_id;
        seq_id_  = 0;
    }

    static UniqueID * GetExclusiveInstance(int type_id)
    {
        assert(type_id < EXCLUSIVE_CNT);

        return Instantiate(type_id);
    }

    static UniqueID * Instantiate(int type_id)
    {
        if(type_to_obj_map_.find(type_id) == type_to_obj_map_.end())
        {
            type_to_obj_map_[type_id] = new UniqueID(type_id);
        }

        return type_to_obj_map_[type_id];
    }
};
```

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has a better/different suggestion.